# Install Ubuntu on very old laptop

Tags: laptop, centrino

I have a very old laptop with the following specs:

Intel Centrino Duo @ 1.83GHz
RAM 1.49 GB

Currently it runs Windows Server 2003 R2 (for some reason).

I want to install a Linux distro,(much preferably) Ubuntu.. in order to develop a Python/Django app.

Which Ubuntu version should I go for?

Please tell me if you need further info about the laptop.

Comment: Install `lubuntu`.

Comment: To develop a Python/Django app I would not vote for Ubuntu at all. You can use a much more lightweight Linux distro.

Comment: I would suggest Lubuntu too. How much RAM is there in the computer? If not more than 1 GB, it might be better with the 32-bit version, because it uses less RAM to run a particular program (compared to the 64-bit version). By the way, do you need a graphical desktop environment? If the answer is no, you could also install Ubuntu Server and add the program packages that you want.

Comment: RAM is 1.49 GB. The processor is 32bit of course. And yes I will definitely use graphical enviroment

Comment: Well, if the processor is 32-bit, you need to install from an i386 iso file. (I thought that all the intel 'duo' processors were 64-bit.) Good luck with Lubuntu :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the ubuntu wiki page concerning lubuntu

> We have done many tests and we've found out that Lubuntu can be installed on a Pentium II or Celeron system with 128 MB of RAM, but such a system would not perform well enough for daily use.
>
> With 256MB - 384MB of RAM, the performance will be better and the system will be more usable.
>
> With 512MB of RAM, you don't need to worry much.
>
> The default "Desktop" installer requires 384-800 MB of RAM (depending on selected options.) If you have problems, please use the alternative installer.

[Click here](http://lubuntu.me/downloads/) to go to the lubuntu download page